# Remove 0's From NSMutableArray of NSNumbers

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I am trying to scan through an NSMutableArray and remove all 0's.  (They are wrapped in NSNumber objects).  I was trying to just use a for loop to search through, but I come across the issue that once I remove an object, it causes an index out of bounds issue for future iterations.  I can't think of a logical way to easily solve this issue.

My current code is this:

```
    for(int i =0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    if(!abs([[array objectAtIndex: i] floatValue]) > 0.0)
    {
              [array removeObjectAtIndex: i];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix up my loop or use a special method/function to just eliminate all 0s?

Comment: The problem with doing this is that if you remove the object at index X, the object at index X+1 goes to index X.

Comment: Yeah thats what I discovered the hard way, but how would I correct this problem?  I considered just doing an "i--" in the IF.  But then the "i < [array count]" still goes outside of the array bounds because we removed objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using NSArray's `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method with a simple block, like so:

```
NSPredicate *notZero = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
    ^BOOL(id evalObject,NSDictionary * options) {
        return [evalObject boolValue];
    }];
array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:notZero];
```

The logic in the block is simple, any float which is non-zero is truthy, and thus passes the predicate.

Comment: Could you explain how this works?  I dont understand that whole NSPredicate line.  Where does it state != 0?

Comment: Casting a float to BOOL handles this for you, it's built in to the language. Any float which is non-zero casts to BOOL as YES (or, true, 1).  The rest is just wrapping that part up into a block, and wrapping the block as a predicate, which NSArray is ready to use to filter with.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay I gotchya.  So 0's would be Nos.  All else would be Yes'es.  I see :) Would this be faster than using loops like I was before?  Because the other answer did work fine also and involved less changes to my code, so now i'm wondering why you prefer this?

Comment: See my comment there for why I prefer this way. I do think the loop method would be faster, it's just more dangerous and breaks a programming rule-of-thumb.

Comment: Ahhh okay.  Well im still in the learning stages so I'll take the safe + rule method.  Thanks man! :D

Comment: I peeked at the documentation, and NSNumber has a boolValue method. Same logic, though: 0 = false, anything else is true.

Answer (score 2):

There's a more elegant option when you are using NSNumbers:

```
[array removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
```

It's simply as that because `removeObject:` removes all occurrences in the array of a given object. Comparison of objects is based on `isEqual:` method so when it comes to NSNumbers it's not comparing pointers but values.

Answer (score 1):

Start at the other end.

```
for (int i = array.count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    ...
```

Comment: This was so simple and worked perfectly.  Can't believe this didn't cross my mind.  Thanks!

Comment: This still leads to mutating an array while iterating it, which is a rule of thumb I am not usually comfortable breaking. It is good, however, that with this technique you are not calling count on the array at ever iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what ctrahey suggested, but perhaps a more readable/understandable approach, is using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]`:

```
NSPredicate *nonZero = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:nonZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

dont remove items in the array your are iterating. instead add them to another array. and remove them afterwards.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:myArray.count];

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count ; i++){
    NSNumber *num = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (num.doubleValue == 0) [array addObject:num];
}

[myArray removeObjectsInArray:array];
```